# How to use Vertex Weights with a Command (Shrink/Fatten)?

Tags: edit-mode, vertex-weights

here's the situation...

i have an animal head modeled.  i want to create layered "shells" of the mesh to simulate fluffiness of the fur.  (forget about other ways to do fur, for now.)

shrink/fatten will do what i want, but i need to control it -- for example the broad areas like cheek, chin, throat, will need lots of fattening (long fur), and the muzzle, around the eyes, etc, will need minimal fuzz (more velvety), and the rest in between.

so i thought i could paint weights -- lower weights around the short fur areas, max weights around the long fur areas...  but then how can i combine that with the shrink/fatten operation?

Answer (score 0):

Sculpting seems the way to go? But you could always aim a *Displace* modifier at a vertex-group, and paint weights into that..

[image]

You could even stack, say, 2 *Displace* modifiers, and a couple of groups. If they were both set to displace along 'Normal' then the second would pick up the normals generated by the first, so you could brush in undercuts.

Comment: oh, excellent!  i will look at that, thanks :)